# Accessing a single time result in $_SESSION['pickup_time']

Tags: php

I'm trying to access a single time result stored in $_SESSION['pickup_time']

When I ran this to find out what's in the variable

```
echo var_dump($_SESSION['pickup_time']) . "<br />";
```

This is the results I'm getting

```
string(8) "07:30:00"
string(8) "07:30:00"
```

How do I put the value `07:30` in a variable called `$userpickuptime`?

**Updated for @tebe**

```
            echo '<pre>' , var_dump($_SESSION['pickup_time']) , '</pre>';
            // init the var
            $userpickuptime = $_SESSION['pickup_time'];
            // and echo it
            echo $userpickuptime;
```

Results as below

```
string(8) "06:30:00"
06:30:00
string(8) "06:30:00"
06:30:00
```

Eventually I only want `06:30` in `$userpickuptime`

**Updated for @bobi**

```
            $userpickuptime = $_SESSION['pickup_time'];
            echo $userpickuptime;
```

The results is

```
06:30:0006:30:00
```

What do I do so that only `06:30:00` is in `$userpickuptime` ?

This system isn't developed by me. I'm not sure why it is executed twice :(

Comment: you print out 2 times pickup_time , remove echo '<pre>' , var_dump($_SESSION['pickup_time']) , '</pre>'; and will be printed only 1 time

Comment: I updated the question for your further advice @bobi

Comment: comment the echo $userpickuptime and replace with print_r($_SESSION['pickup_time']) and let me know the result

Comment: Hi @bobi this shows up `06:30:0006:30:00` . I only want to store `06:30:00` in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since result from $_SESSION['pickup_time'] is 06:30:0006:30:00 you have 2 options

1. fix $_SESSION['pickup_time'] to return correct string time
2. split string and get the part you want

[example](https://onlinephp.io/c/c4dc5)

```
$time = '06:30:0006:30:00';
$split_time = mb_substr($time, 0, 8);

echo $split_time;
```

output

```
06:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is simply executed twice. That's the reason for the timestamp echoed two times.

It is also not required to `echo` a `var_dump`, since `var_dump` itself has no return value. So, it's enough to do it this way.

```
var_dump($_SESSION['pickup_time']);
```

And regarding your question, how to put a value in a variable, you can do this like so.

```
// init the var
$userpickuptime = $_SESSION['pickup_time'];

// and echo it
echo $userpickuptime;
```

Comment: Hi, how do I put only 1 single value in a variable? Coz right now it's giving me the value 2 times which I don't want

Comment: I updated the question for your further advice @tebe

Comment: Thanks. Looking at your debug output above, I still think that the code is executed twice. @iwani-khalid Is the code working for you?